# Pago con Redsys Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas con una página que cree hace algún tiempo con Laravel 5.8 y con el metodo de pago de Redsys.

El problema está, en que tengo campos para identificar si se a realizado el pago, por ejemplo; 0 a la espera, 1 pagado, 2 Fallido y 3 Cancelado.

Cuando compras en la página te redirige a una página externa del banco, eso regresa una respuesta de como a ido la compra.

Bien paso a enseñaros como lo tengo programado, cuando le dan confirmar compra en el chekout, lo hacen del siguiente modo:

Es un formulario con una ruta que lleva el controlador lo lleva a la página del banco.

```
{{ url('redsys') }}"
```

La ruta:

```
Route::get('/redsys', ['as' => 'redsys', 'uses' => 'RedsysController@index']);
```

Y en el controlador lo siguiente:

```
class RedsysController extends Controller
{
    public static function index(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request);
        try{
            $cart = Session::get('cart');
            $contador = Cart::count(); 
            $consecutivos = DB::table('consecutivos')->first();
            $anio = date('Y');
            $consecutivo = $consecutivos->consecutivo;
            $idpedido = $anio."".$consecutivo;
            $consenew = $consecutivo + 1;
            $affected = DB::table('consecutivos')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->update([ 'consecutivo' => $consenew ]);

            foreach ($cart as $key => $order) {
                //dd($order); 
                $data = json_decode($order, true);
                   
                foreach($data as $key => $item){
                    $opt = new Order;
                    $opt->cliente = $request->input('persona');
                    $opt->email = $request->input('email');
                    $opt->telefono = $request->input('telefono');
                    $opt->producto = $item['name'];
                    $opt->ayuno = $item['options']['ayuno'];
                    $opt->cantidad = $item['qty'];
                    $opt->total = round($item['subtotal'], 2);
                    $opt->ticket = $idpedido;
                    $opt->sms = $request->input('sms1');
                    $opt->pinchado = 0;
                    $opt->estado = 0;
                    $opt->save();
                }         
            }
            //dd($request);
            $key = config('redsys.key');
            $display = false;
            Redsys::setMerchantData($idpedido);
            Redsys::setAmount($request->total);
            Redsys::setOrder(time());
            Redsys::setMerchantcode(config('redsys.merchantcode'));
            Redsys::setCurrency('978');
            Redsys::setTransactiontype('0');
            Redsys::setTerminal(config('redsys.terminal'));
            Redsys::setMethod('T');
            Redsys::setNotification(config('redsys.url_notification'));
            Redsys::setUrlOk(config('redsys.url_ok')); //Url OK
            Redsys::setUrlKo(config('redsys.url_ko')); //Url KO
            Redsys::setVersion('HMAC_SHA256_V1');
            Redsys::setTradeName('ddddd');
            Redsys::setTitular('dddddd');
            Redsys::setEnviroment(config('redsys.enviroment'));

            $signature = Redsys::generateMerchantSignature($key);
            Redsys::setMerchantSignature($signature);
            Redsys::setAttributesSubmit('btn_submit', 'btn_id', 'Enviar', 'display:none');
            return Redsys::executeRedirection();       
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $form;  
    }

    public function respuestaPago(Request $request)
    {
        $key = config('redsys.key');
        $parameters = Redsys::getMerchantParameters($request->input('Ds_MerchantParameters'));
        $DsResponse = $parameters["Ds_Response"];
        $DsResponse += 0;

        //dd($request);

        //dd($parameters);

        if (Redsys::check($key, $request->input()) && $DsResponse <= 99) {

            $orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->where('ticket', $parameters['Ds_MerchantData'])
                ->update([
                    'estado' => '1'
                ]);

            $cart = Session::get('cart');
            $contador = Cart::count();             

            Cart::destroy();

            $datos = DB::table('orders')->where('ticket', $parameters['Ds_MerchantData'])->first();
            $emadalCLiente = $datos->email;
            Mail::send('emails.compra', ['datos'=>$datos], function($message) use ($emadalCLiente)
    
            {
            $message->to($emadalCLiente)
                ->subject('Gracias por su pedido');
            });

            Mail::send('emails.compraAdmin', ['datos'=>$datos], function($message) use ($emadalCLiente)
            {
            $message->to('info@email.es')
                ->subject('Nuevo pedido');
            });

            return redirect('pago-realizado-correctamente')->with('info', 'Pedido realizado correctamente!');


        } else {

            $orders = DB::table('orders')
                ->where('ticket', $parameters['Ds_MerchantData'])
                ->update([
                    'estado' => '3'
                ]);

            return redirect('pago-fallido')->with('fail', 'No se a podido procesar el pago!');
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hago es tal como llega al TPV guardo el pedido en la base de datos con un número de ticket. Luego depende la respuesta de pago, con el número de ticket que envio a Redsys si el pago a sido correcto hago un `->update(['estado' => '1']);` para cambiar el pedido a pagado, y si no a salido bien lo modifico por un 3.

Pero están habiendo varios pedidos que les llega el dinero al banco, pero en cambio me deja el pedido en "espera" que es el número "0", que estoy haciendo mal, por más que lo veo, creo que esta correcto.

Comment: Verificaste que `$parameters['Ds_MerchantData']` retorne el número de Ticket correcto? O verificaste que efectivamente esté entrando al condicional?

Comment: Hol a@JonatanLavado en su momento cuando lo programe en modo pruebas fucnionaba bien y trae siempre el ticket sin problemas. El problema es que ahora esta en modo producción el TPV y no se como realizar más pruebas sin comprar

Answer (score 0):

A nosotros no ha pasado algunas veces que si no le mandas exactamente un formato que requiere redsys da error o te lo manda vacío.

Nosotros usamos `number_format($precio, 2, '.', '')`, para evitar estos problemas.

Espero haberte ayudado!!

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, pero el importe llega bien al redsys a pesar de dejar el estado en espera

Comment: Perdona, entendí mal tu pregunta, has verificado que la url url_ok, url_ko y url_callback están correctas, redsys suele enviar los datos a la callback cuando ha ido todo ok.

Comment: En su momento cuando lo programe en modo pruebas el tpv estaba todo correcto, no creo que ahora se haya estropeado solo

Comment: Sabes si existe algún modo para hacer comprobaciones sin necesidad de poner el tpv en modo pruebas de nuevo @Francisco Manuel Gonzalez Triv

Comment: No, tienes que usarlo en modo pruebas, lo malo es que hay discrepancias entre el entorno de pruebas y el real. En el real falla muchas veces de que no llega una respuesta a la url de notificación si el cliente en la pasarela no le da a continuar y cierra la ventana directamente.

Comment: Entonces que haces habitualmente tu? Por que claro así la plataforma no funciona correctamente, y evidentemente al cliente no le gusta

Comment: Nosotros registramos el intento de pago y verificamos manualmente, normalmente suele ser el 2% de todos los pagos, aunque en nuestra empresa casi todos los pagos son mediante transferencias unificas ya que son grandes pedidos de miles de euros.

Comment: Claro yo verifico el pago a través de la respuesta de redsys, no se bien que puedo hacer